# open an url in startup when invoking notepad++.exe

Tags: notepad++

is it possible to send an url to Notepad++.exe and have it to read the source and display as text?

Example:

```
notepad++.exe https://myurl.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a successfully tested solution after you get [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) tool:

Create this file **showsrc.bat** (use actual paths at the beginning of each line)

```
C:\Your\Path\To\curl.exe %1 > %temp%\curl.out
C:\Your\Path\To\notepad++.exe %temp%\curl.out
```

Then run the file for example like this:

```
showsrc.bat https://stackoverflow.com
```

...and Notepad++ will open with expected content.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing mentioned in the documentation. I think Notepad++ is not able to download a file from an URL.
When you open an URL via file open dialog Windows itself is downloading the file to a temporary directory and Notepad++ is opening this file. As far as I know this should work with almost any Windows Application.

Comment: yes I think you're right. it just would be nice to select Open In Notepad++ from a page in Firefox. I found an extension that let's me open current url in a custom software, but if np++ doesn't accept an url as parameter when calling the exe, this wont be possible

Comment: you could just create a wrapper script as @miroxlav answered and open this in custom extenstion. of course you need to add parameters to this script and not hardcode the url. this will only work if the requested page is public and does not depend on session variables